# Compare jsonb_path_query_array result with another array (ignoring ordering)

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `table1` that looks like this:

```
sentence  data  
good     [{"pred": "yes", 'prob': 0.6}, {"pred": "maybe", "prob": 0.4}, {"pred": "another", "prob": 0.7}]
bad      [{"pred": "unexpected", "prob": 0.4}, {"pred": "uncool", "prob": 0.3}]
```

and another table `table2` that looks like:

```
sentence  real_values  
good     ["another", "yes"]
bad      ["no"]
```

I want to output a boolean column signifying if the set of values in array `real_values` matches set of `pred` values from `data` (comparing only values where `prob` >= 0.5)

So, for this, the result will be:

```
  sentence | preds              |   real_values       |  is_match
-----------+-------
 good      | ['yes', 'another'] | ["another", "yes"]  |  true
 bad       | []                 | ["no"]              |  false   
(2 rows)
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
SELECT sentence, 
       jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$[*] ? (@.prob >= 0.5).pred') as preds,
       table2.real_values,
(
    ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$[*] ? (@.prob >= 0.5).pred')) <@ ARRAY(SELECT table2.real_values)
    AND ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_path_query_array(data, '$[*] ? (@.prob >= 0.5).pred')) @> ARRAY(SELECT table2.real_values)
    ) AS is_match   
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN table2
WHERE table1.sentence = table2.sentence
GROUP BY table1.sentence, table2.real_values, table1.preds
;
```

AND it returns me:

```
  sentence | preds              |   real_values       |  is_match
-----------+-------
 good      | ['yes', 'another'] | ['another', 'yes']  |  false
 bad       | []                 | ['no']              |  false
```

The `is_match` should have been true for the first case, but is not. It does however, work when there is only 1 element in the array, not sure what is wrong with the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to convert the JSONB values to native arrays. The `@>` operator also works for JSONB values.

```
select t1.sentence, 
       jsonb_path_query_array(t1.data, '$[*] ? (@.prob >= 0.5).pred') as preds,
       t2.real_values,
       jsonb_path_query_array(t1.data, '$[*] ? (@.prob >= 0.5).pred') @> t2.real_values as is_match
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t1.sentence = t2.sentence
```